# Kivy App label not updating but Psutil module are updating

Tags: python, kivy, psutil

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import psutil

battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
percent = str(battery.percent)

class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text = percent + "%")


while True:
    Application().run()
```

The label does not change, even though the percent variable has changed. Though the computer shows the battery level 60%, the app shows the battery level of when the App started.

Comment: There is nothing in your code to update the `Label` or the battery percent after the initial value.

Comment: how may i do that?

Comment: i am quite new to kivy

Comment: by the way thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [clock.schedule_interval](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_interval) to schedule regular updates. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import psutil

class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 2)
        return Label(text="Unknown")

    def update(self, dt):
        percent = str(psutil.sensors_battery().percent)
        self.root.text = percent + "%"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().run()
```